# Shell script runs manually, but doesn't behave as expected when started by systemd

Tags: bash, shell-script, fedora, systemd, google-drive

I'm trying to get `google-drive-ocamlfuse` to mount on Fedora 35 Linux at startup.

I've installed `opam` and successfully installed `google-drive-ocamlfuse`.

Because this is on a laptop using WiFi to connect to the Internet, I created a bash script to run at startup, [as per these instructions on the `google-drive-ocamlfuse` wiki](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Automounting#mount-when-using-wifi):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  # check to see if there is a connection by pinging a Google server
  if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
    # if connected, mount the drive and break the loop
    /home/myusername/.opam/default/bin/google-drive-ocamlfuse /home/myusername/GoogleDrive; break;
  else
    # if not connected, wait for one second and then check again
    sleep 1
  fi
done
```

I've placed the script in `/usr/local/bin`, though the blurb on the wiki does indeed say to put it in `/home/username/bin`. I see no reason why this would matter one way or the other.

In `/etc/systemd/system`, I have a systemd service I made, `mount-google-drive.service` that's just supposed to run the script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run shell script to launch google-drive-ocamlfuse at startup

[Service]
User=myusername
Group=myusername
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I run `$ /usr/local/bin/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh` manually, then the Google Drive folder mounts just fine. However, I can't seem to get the systemd service to successfully run the script at startup.

I modified my `~/.bashrc` file with `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.opam/default/bin/` so as to permanently make `google-drive-ocamlfuse` available in my `$PATH`. I've run `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, and rebooted.

`/usr/local/bin/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh` has permissions `-rwxr-xr-x`.

`/etc/systemd/system/mount-google-drive.service` has permissions `-rwxr-xr-x`.

When I run `$ sudo systemctl status mount-google-drive.service`, it appears that systemd has indeed run the script, but for some reason it isn't *actually* mounting the `~/GoogleDrive` folder:

```
$ sudo systemctl status mount-google-drive.service 
○ mount-google-drive.service - Run shell script to launch google-drive-ocamlfuse at startup
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mount-google-drive.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2021-12-05 22:36:19 CST; 2min 58s ago
    Process: 1360 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1360 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 67ms

Dec 05 22:36:11 fedora systemd[1]: Started Run shell script to launch google-drive-ocamlfuse at startup.
Dec 05 22:36:11 fedora mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh[1382]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Dec 05 22:36:12 fedora mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh[1573]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Dec 05 22:36:13 fedora mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh[1614]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Dec 05 22:36:14 fedora mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh[1616]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Dec 05 22:36:15 fedora mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh[1618]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Dec 05 22:36:16 fedora mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh[1620]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Dec 05 22:36:17 fedora mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh[1622]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Dec 05 22:36:19 localhost-live.lan systemd[1]: mount-google-drive.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

To check to make sure that `myusername` is actually running the script, I run `$ su - myusername -c 'bash /usr/local/bin/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse.sh'` and that mounts the drive perfectly, as expected.

Why does systemd seem to run the script "successfully" but in reality it's not mounting the `~/GoogleDrive` folder via `google-drive-ocamlfuse` as when I run the bash script manually?

Comment: You should address the network error message, `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: @roaima That's the actual purpose of the looping bash script--waiting for WiFi to connect before attempting to mount the filesystem.

Comment: I agree that there doesn’t seem to be a reason why it would make a difference, but have you tried placing the script in the location mentioned by the docs?

Comment: What output do you see when you run the script by hand?

Comment: @Christopher Just added some info that yes, it mounts when I run as `myusername`. I might be not understanding though--how do I know if systemd itself is not using `myusername`?

Comment: Can you not use `After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target` in your mount service? What am I missing?

Comment: Found your question while searching for an answer to a similar question. [This blog may help](https://medium.com/@artur.klauser/mounting-google-drive-on-raspberry-pi-f5002c7095c2)

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the "`~`" with the full path. "`~`" is a `$SHELL` feature. E.g. mount `/home/user240467/GoogleDrive` rather than `~/GoogleDrive`. Ensure (`man mkdir`) that `/home/user240467/GoogleDrive` exists.

You're welcome to download, use, and modify my `net-o-matic` script.

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.

Comment: Where do you see that I'm even using `~`? I'm not. Nowhere in the shell script or the sytstemd service is that notation used.

Comment: Would have been nice if the OP followed up on this issue. I am having a very similar problem. I'm pretty tired so this is probably more of the problem. When I figure out what resolves my issue I will post the solution in here since this guy didn't care to do anything.

Comment: Turns out my issue wasn't related to this question as much as I thought or I'd post an answer here. I'm pretty sure the issue the OP is having is a permissions issue. This is why the documentation he was following suggested placing the shell script under the home directory. When mounting drives outside the user permission scope sudo or root is required. I think this is what is happening. I need sleep.